# Send IconicTile Notification in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, push-notification, mpns

I am trying to send Iconic Tile Notification from Server to Client using node2dm. Node2dm provides us with 'mpns' module which I am using to send Messages. I want my notification to look like the first tile in the image and not like the second one.
[image]

Now I have two issue.

=>. First is, I am able to send notifications of second type where notification count appears in a circle. But I am not able to clear that notification count. I used

`mpns.sendTile(pushUri, backgroundImage, count, title, backBackgroundImage)`

for this. I tried sending `count=0` for clearing the notification from tile but it didn't work.

=>. Second problem is, I tried sending notification of first type from above image since I was not able to clear the notification count for previous one. And also this looks more elegant. For this I used

`mpns.sendIconicTile(pushUri, backgroundColor, count, title, iconImage, smallIconImage, wideContent1, wideContent2, wideContent3)`

But with this. I am not even getting any tile update at all. There is an option of providing `id` in `sendIconicTile()` function, but I dont know what to pass it there. I don't have an id for my tile. Its primary default tile which I am trying to update, not a secondary tile. So I think 'id' shouldn't be required.

Can someone please help me with this. Or suggest some other way to update my tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not familiar with node2dm, but I'll try to help. For the first problem, if you were sending notification by yourself you would set this line `<wp:Count Action="Clear"></wp:Count>` in notification XML payload. Now I'm not sure if you can do that with node2dm, but they should provide a way to set that.

The second problem looks as your client application doesn't have Iconic tile template. You need to change that in you app's WMAppManifest.xml. It needs to look something like this

```
<Tokens>
  <PrimaryToken TokenID="YouAppNameToken" TaskName="_default">
    <TemplateIconic>
      <SmallImageURI IsResource="false" IsRelative="true">TileIcon.png</SmallImageURI>
      <Count>0</Count>          
      <IconImageURI IsResource="false" IsRelative="true">TileIcon.png</IconImageURI>
      <Title>Your title</Title>
    </TemplateIconic>        
  </PrimaryToken>
</Tokens>
```

Comment: Ya. I figured it out after sometime that I need to set IconicTemplate in WMAppManifest.xaml file. But thanks for your answer. And resetting the count in my first problem, I reset it on every app start.

Comment: But now I have another issue. I have resized icons for IconImage as 130x202 and SmallIconImage as 70x110, and have added them to Assets folder. But they come up as blank white circle. Ant suggestions?

Comment: Yes, images for the iconic tile cannot be in color. Everything that is not transparent on the image will be shown in white, and transparent parts will be in the phone accent color.

Comment: Hey. thanks for the help. Again I am not getting tile updates for mobiles running on windows phone 8.0. It is running perfectly fine for test phone running on windows phone 8.1. but other test phone and emulators running on 8.0 are not getting any updates. Can you help with this. Thanks

Comment: There shouldn't be difference, unless you implemented the 8.1 version as Windows Phone XAML app, then there is a huge difference. But since you are deploying the same application to both 8.0 and 8.1 devices I suppose you built it using the Silverlight framework. It's hard to tell, but I can only guess that you maybe forgot to call BindToShellTile() on your HttpNotificationChannel object?